# Is it possible to round the edtes of a round corner

Tags: edit-mode, bevel

[image]I wanted to try and make a controller but cant bevel into a rounded corner

Pretty much what I am asking is if I were to trace a c shape this is top view (C) how would I round the 2 points keeping in mind it was traced and does not already have smooth edges. It is also extruded to be thicker so a 3D C shape.

I will post an image if its required

Comment: hello, yes please show a picture, it's a bit hard to understand

Comment: I will not be able to add the image until tonight as I'm not near my pc

Comment: added the image

Answer (score 0):

Add a subdivision-surface modifier, and then add loopcuts around the top and bottom. Move these loopcuts near the top and bottom of the mesh to help shape the Sub-surface modifier.